# PHP website always redirecting

Tags: php, nginx

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with Nginx and PHP-FPM.

I would like to add a vhost (I have added this in my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default config file)

```
                server {
                    listen       80;
                include /etc/nginx/cloudflare-allow.conf;
                  deny all;
                    server_name  testerij.star-servers.nl;
                    access_log /dev/null;
                    error_log /dev/null;
                    location / {
                    root   /usr/share/nginx/test;
                    index index.php  index.html index.htm;
                    }
                    location ~ \.php$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                    fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
                    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    }
                }
```

My problem is that this vhost is always redirecting to another domain (on the same server) when using .php files. When I create a .html file (index.html) this does not happen, but with index.php, it does happen.

I don´t have any clue, can you help me?

File cloudflare-allow.conf:

## IPv4

```
        allow 199.27.128.0/21;
        allow 173.245.48.0/20;
        allow 103.21.244.0/22;
        allow 103.22.200.0/22;
        allow 103.31.4.0/22;
        allow 141.101.64.0/18;
        allow 108.162.192.0/18;
        allow 190.93.240.0/20;
        allow 188.114.96.0/20;
        allow 197.234.240.0/22;
        allow 198.41.128.0/17;
        allow 162.158.0.0/15;
        allow 104.16.0.0/12;

        # IPv6
        allow 2400:cb00::/32;
        allow 2606:4700::/32;
        allow 2803:f800::/32;
        allow 2405:b500::/32;
        allow 2405:8100::/32;

        # Load Balancer IPv4
        allow 104.155.1.229;
```

Comment: Might help to see your PHP file

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt It doesn´t matter what´s in my PHP file.

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt I can type for example, <?php echo ´aap´;?>  and it will still redirect

Comment: What's in /etc/nginx/cloudflare-allow.conf

Comment: I have added that file to my question :)